# Access Large Array with Preassigned Index

Tags: list-manipulation

I wish to use a preassigned variable to index a large array many times. For example:

```
a = {i,j+1,k-1};
b = {i+1,j,k-2};
```

I know I can do this several ways but for conciseness in formula I want to use the double bracket assignment such as:

```
Ex[[ Sequence@@a ]] + Ey[[ Sequence@@b]]
```

In a large number of calculations however the sequence operation adds about 50% time overhead. Is there a way without the time cost overhead? thanks

---

The form of these two expressions are constructed elsewhere in the program

```
ind = {{i, j + 1, k}, {i - 1, j, k - 1}};
```

and need to be passed to a function, e.g.

```
f[in_] := Module[{a = in[[1]], b = in[[2]]},
    Table[Ex[[Sequence @@ a]] + Ey[[Sequence @@ b]], {m, 500}, {i, 2, 8}, 
      {j, 2, 8}, {k, 2, 8}]];
```

If I did not have the requirement to construct the index form somewhere else I could simply put:

```
g[]:= Table[
  Ex[[i, j + 1, k]] + Ey[[i - 1, j, k - 1]], {m, 500}, {i, 2, 8}, {j, 
 2,8}, {k, 2, 8}]

Ex = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 10, 10, 10}];
Ey = RandomReal[{0, 10}, {10, 10, 10, 10}];

AbsoluteTiming[f[ind];]
```

{0.651337, Null}

```
AbsoluteTiming[g[];]
```

{0.0892097, Null}

Comment: You say "assignment" but I see only an addition. Is this a typo?

Answer (score 5):

You may use `Extract`:

```
m = 100;
n = 10000;
Ex = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, m, m}];
Ey = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, {m, m, m}];
a = RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, 3}];
b = RandomInteger[{1, m}, {n, 3}];

r1 = Table[Ex[[Sequence @@ a[[i]]]] + Ey[[Sequence @@ b[[i]]]], {i, 1, Length[a]}]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r2 = Extract[Ex, a] + Extract[Ey, b]; // AbsoluteTiming // First
r1 == r2
```

> 0.103876
>
> 0.000698
>
> True

---

## Edit

In the meantime, I got to the conclusion that the reason for `f` being slower than `g` is that `Sequence` is not compilable. So let us perform the compilation by hand:

```
f2[in_] := Quiet@Block[{X, XX, Y, YY},
    With[{XX = Part[X, Sequence @@ in[[1]]], YY = Part[Y, Sequence @@ in[[2]]]},
     Compile[{{X, _Real, 4}, {Y, _Real, 4}},
       Table[XX + YY, {m, 1, 500}, {i, 2, 8}, {j, 2, 8}, {k, 2, 8}],
       CompilationTarget -> "WVM"
       ];
     cf[Ex, Ey]
     ]
    ];
```

Now we have:

```
aa = f[{{i, j + 1, k}, {i - 1, j, k - 1}}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
bb = g[]; // RepeatedTiming // First
cc = f2[{{i, j + 1, k}, {i - 1, j, k - 1}}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aa == bb == cc
```

> 0.692
>
> 0.090
>
> 0.0775
>
> True

A further speed-up can be obtained by replacing `Part` by `Compile`GetElement`:

```
f3[in_] := Block[{X, XX, Y, YY},
   With[{XX = Compile`GetElement[X, Sequence @@ in[[1]]], YY = Compile`GetElement[Y, Sequence @@ in[[2]]]},
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 4}, {Y, _Real, 4}},
      Table[XX + YY, {m, 1, 500}, {i, 2, 8}, {j, 2, 8}, {k, 2, 8}],
      CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ];
    cf[Ex, Ey]
    ]
   ];
```

Runtime test:

```
dd = f3[{{i, j + 1, k}, {i - 1, j, k - 1}}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aa == dd
```

> 0.028
>
> True

Finally, let me say that handing over the code for the indices by the symbolic code `{{i, j + 1, k}, {i - 1, j, k - 1}}` is *very* fragile. A more robust way would be to submit functions that generate the symbolic code:

```
f4[in_] := Quiet@Block[{X, XX, Y, YY, i, j, k},
   With[{XX = Compile`GetElement[X, Sequence @@ in[[1]][i, j, k]], YY = Compile`GetElement[Y, Sequence @@ in[[2]][i, j, k]]},
    Compile[{{X, _Real, 4}, {Y, _Real, 4}},
      Table[XX + YY, {m, 1, 500}, {i, 2, 8}, {j, 2, 8}, {k, 2, 8}],
      CompilationTarget -> "WVM",
      RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
      ];
    cf[Ex, Ey]
    ]
   ];
```

Test:

```
ee = f4[{{i, j, k} \[Function] {i, j + 1, k}, {i, j, k} \[Function] {i - 1, j, k - 1}}]; // RepeatedTiming // First
aa == ee
```

> 0.028
>
> True

Comment: I have not explained myself well. The indices to be used are created

Comment: I have not explained myself well:

Comment: Then please clarify in your post. It may help to post the code that you actually used.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed explanation. It is very helpful

Comment: You're welcome.